# Return two prime numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

My problem statement is:

> Given an even number (greater than 2), return two prime numbers whose sum will be equal to given number. There are several combinations possible. Print only first such pair.

The code I have so far is:

```
n=int(input())
lst=[]
for i in range(2,n):
    count=0
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        if(i%j==0):
            count+=1
    if(count==2):
        lst.append(i)
print(lst)
for k in range(len(lst)):
    for g in range(k,len(lst)):
        if((lst[k]+lst[g])==n):
            print(lst[k],end=" ")
            print(lst[g])
            break
```

If my input is `74`, the expected output is `3 71`. But my output for above code is:

```
3 71  
7 67  
13 61  
31 43  
37 37
```

I need just the first line (`3 71`).

Comment: You are only `break`ing from the inner loop, not the outer one. Try wrapping this into a function and `return` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should break out of both loops. You presently break out of only the inner for loop, hence why you have multiple matching cases.

```
found = False
for k in range(len(lst)):
   if found:
       break
   for g in range(k,len(lst)):
       if((lst[k]+lst[g])==n):
            print(lst[k],end=" ")
            print(lst[g])
            found = True
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`for-else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) construct to `continue` the outer loop if the inner loop did not find a valid pair; otherwise `break` both the inner loop and the outer loop to get out of both loops once a valid pair is found:

```
for k in range(len(lst)):
    for g in range(k, len(lst)):
        if ((lst[k] + lst[g]) == n):
            print(lst[k], end=" ")
            print(lst[g])
            break
    else:
        continue
    break
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function numbers(range) {
  function isPrime(n) {
    let prime = true;
    for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
      if (n % i == 0) return (prime = false);
    }
    return prime;
  }

  for (let i = 3; i <= range; i++) {
    if (isPrime(i) && isPrime(range - i) && i != range - i) {
      console.log(i, range - i);
      break;
    }
  }
}

numbers(12); //Output: 5, 7
```